# Voom function from limma package and Normalization on counts data

Tags: r, bioconductor, normalization

I know that Voom function from [limma](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/limma.html) package from Bioconductor converts raw counts into log-CPM values and then Normalization is applied on that, with normalize.method argument.

I would like to know clearly for RNA-Seq data:

1. how this normalization is done (statistically) ?
2. normalization across samples and normalization across genes. But don't the know how it is done statistically.

Answer (score 2):

As you answered yourself @Death Metal, `voom` will by default not perform additional normalization.
However in virtually all cases you would want to do some kind of [normalization](https://dx.doi.org/10.1093%2Fbib%2Fbbx008) at least to correct for differences in sequenced reads between the samples. This is why in the [manual](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/limma/inst/doc/usersguide.pdf) (page 71 right at the top) the `calcNormFactors` function from  [`edgeR`](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/edgeR.html) is used. This does a global `TMM` normalization for differences in library size.

Basically `voom` assumes that you did a normalization and will not do a second one because this could cause all kinds of problems.

In some cases you may prefer normalization other than `TMM`, for example if the number of genes detected in your samples is widely different. In this case is could be better to do `quantile` normalization that is available through the `normalizeBetweenArrays` function in `voom`.
However, this may over-correct your data and get rid of many interesting differences. In these cases I have found [`qsmooth`](https://dx.doi.org/10.1093/biostatistics/kxx028) quite helpful. Here quantile normalization is only applied across groups if the local distributions are similar enough.